# Count of a mutable array shows memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Why [nsmutableArrayObj count] show me 75% memory Leak in instrument. I cant understand this.

Comment: post code so we can tell you the exact problem

Comment: You might be retaining it somewhere. Check ur code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `count` an array, it has to count each object using `NSEnumerator` or a `for` loop. If your array is not released, it will be accessed several times by this loop, causing memory to leak.

You're most definitely not releasing something somewhere, but since you've posted no code I can't give any more details.